# How to list the field names from a Django serializer

Tags: python, django

I have a model serializer and I was wondering how to get a list of the names of the fields of this serializer. Similarly, I know how to get a list of the fields form a model and from a form.

Example model:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    account_holder = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=50)
    age = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    salary = models.DecimalField(blank=False, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

Then the list of fields can be derived from:

```
obj_fields = Account._meta.get_fields()  # as objects
[field.name for field in Account._meta.get_fields()] # as list of strings
# output: ['id', 'account_holder', 'age', 'salary']
```

From the form:

```
class AccountForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Account
```

The list of the form fields (one of the possible methods without derailing into a different topic):

```
fields = AccountForm.base_fields # as dictionary of objects
[field for field in AccountForm.base_fields.keys()] # as list of strings
# output: ['account_holder', 'age', 'salary']
```

And I have a serializer:

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = (
            'id',
            'account_holder',
            'age',
            'salary',
            'age_score',
            'salary_score',
        )
```

which has a few more fields than the model. But for example using the following, it throws an error:

```
>>> AccountSerializer.get_field_names()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ModelSerializer.get_field_names() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'self', 'declared_fields', and 'info'
```

Clearly, I ignore how to use this method and if there is another method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the methods on an instance of the serializer (not the class itself):

```
serializer = AccountSerializer()
fields = serializer.get_fields().keys()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found this one-liner using the serializer class which works fine for me:

```
fields = AccountSerializer.Meta.fields # return a tuple of strings
```

As a note: I find the method by SofienM can give more information out of the object.

Comment: I tried this method but it returns `__all__` when you've used this option in you serializer's Meta class. That's why I considered using an instance of the class instead.